# Show element on form submission

Tags: css, node.js, express, nodemailer

I'm using nodemailer to forward content from a form to an email address.
When the user clicks on the "Submit" button, I want "Message Sent" to appear under the form. 
So I did this:

```js
    transporter.sendMail(info, (error, info) => {
        if(error){
            return console.log(error)
        }
        console.log('Message sent %s', info.messageId)
        res.render('contact', {msg: "message sent"})

    })
```

```css
.sent-message{
    background-color: rgba(0, 130, 0, 0.23);
    color: #005000;
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 <p class="full sent-message">{{{msg}}}</p>
```

Now this works fine, except that the CSS of p tag is always active. So it appears like this before form submission.
[image]

Is there any way for the p tag or the css to show only when the form submission is successful?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the solution. Instead of sending a text via the 'msg' variable, I had to send the whole element via 'msg'.

It goes like this:

```
transporter.sendMail(info, (error, info) => {
  if (error) {
    return console.log(error)
  }
  console.log('Message sent %s', info.messageId)
  res.render('contact', {msg: `<p class="sent-message">Message Sent</p>`})
})
```

and then in the HTML we replace the p tag with:

```
{{{msg}}}
```